# Edit link in MVC4 - Not able to get the value in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

All,
I am trying to edit the data using MVC4.

When I click on Edit link - I could see the param name AND Value getting appended in the querystring but in controller I am unable to get the value for selected row

Controller Code

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
          PhonebookModel PHm =   _phList.Find(x => x.ID == id);
            return View(PHm);
        }
```

Here in controller, I am getting ID as null.. Any clue what I am doing wrong?

Note: I can see the Edit screen but all controls are empty.

Thanks in advance.   cshtml code that generates Edit link @model IEnumerable

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

### Index

@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        
        
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Last
Name)
        
        
    

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    
        
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        
        
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        
        
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { ID = item.ID}) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { ID = item.ID }) 

        
    
}

Comment: Please post the helper code generating the link

Comment: @Index.cshtml I have following code that defines link @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { ID= item.ID}) |

Comment: @Amit - There is no edit link there. Or any link that passes an id. What code generates the link to the `Edit` action?

Comment: @Jack- I have added the code that generates the Edit link

Comment: _phList.Find(x => x.ID == Request["ID"]) and I am able to get the values... Is this a proper way to get value selected from UI to controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the parameter is case sensitive, try changing your ActionLink to:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID})
```

Comment: Yes, Exactly... Parameter is case sensitive... it workd now... also one more thing I tried i.e. getting the value using Request["ParamName"] option  .. see below                                                          public ActionResult Edit()
        {
            
          PhonebookModel m =   _phList.Find(x => x.ID == Request["id"]);
            return View(m);
        }    Is this also a valid way ?

Comment: Yes but why would you want to? MVC handles the binding for you

Comment: Yeah, binding is working for me too after changing the case.. but just wanted to get opinion on Request["id"] .   Thanks.